# variable not accessible from promise's then

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a weird scenario that I don't what caused this.
I have a function that returns a promise and chain to it a 'then' method.
Inside the then method, I can access one of the outer variables, but the other one is undefined.

I thought that I might have a with that name used in the 'then' function and due to hoisting the value is undefined, but there is not.

Here is a simplified version of my case, wondering what can cause such a scenario:

```
class MessageSender {
    constructor(){
    }

    sendMessage(message, options) {
        return somethingThatReturnPromise()
            .then(function (response) {
                // parameter 'message' is object as it should be,
                // but'options' is undefined.
                return response;
            })
        return promise;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a `var options` somewhere that shadows the outer variable. Please show us your actual code.

Comment: …the other possibility is that `sendMessage` simply was called without an `options` argument, or it was set to `undefined` explicitly somehow else.

Comment: Btw, you have two `return`s in the method :-)

Comment: Since JavaScript has lexical scope, in your simplified example, `options` is absolutely accessible inside the inner function. Seems like you simplified too much...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work just fine.

```
function sendMessage(message, options) {
    return somethingThatReturnPromise()
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('message: ' + message);
        console.log('options: ' + options);
        return response;
    });
}

function somethingThatReturnPromise(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve();
        }, 100);
    });
}

console.log('Starting...');
sendMessage('THE MESSAGE', 'THE OPTIONS').then(function(){
    console.log('All done.');
});
```

Returns

```
me@pc:~/dev/test$ node asdf.js 
Starting...
message: THE MESSAGE
options: THE OPTIONS
All done.
```